# Is it possible to change the menu separator?

Tags: menus

Consider the following menu item:

[image: Emacs menu bar]

Notice that the separator is "--" (between `*Messages*` and `Next Buffer`). Is there a way to change the separator? I would like to change it to "======" instead.

The separator is apparently set by `menu-bar-separator`, which is defined in [subr.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.1/lisp/subr.el#L5727-L5728):

```lisp
(defconst menu-bar-separator '("--")
  "Separator for menus.")
```

It appears to be a constant. Does this mean that it is impossible to change the menu bar separator?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: It actually is not limited to the menu-bar, and it is in no way a separator for the menu bar. It's used to separate menu items in a menu (and not just a menu-bar menu). You can change the value of a `defconst` variable, but the purpose of a `defconst` is to indicate to humans that the variable normally *should* not be changed by anyone or any program. In this case, as far as I can see, changing the value (at runtime, at least) *does* not change the behavior.

Comment: I just filed bug #[45806](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45806), about the misleading name and paltry doc.